# Reusing space after deleting rows in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

In Oracle the space allocated for data after `INSERT INTO` operation is not cleaned up when deleting rows from the table. Instead, after `DELETE FROM` operation some "waste space" is left. So what happens when I do `INSERT INTO` after `DELETE FROM` - does it span this "waste space" or allocates new space again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the Oracle Concepts manual](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/tablecls.htm#GUID-85BE900A-0047-4B7C-A992-F1E35B640CA3):

> By default, a table is organized as a heap, which means that the
>   database places rows where they fit best rather than in a
>   user-specified order. Thus, a heap-organized table is an unordered
>   collection of rows. As users add rows, the database places the rows in
>   the first available free space in the data segment. Rows are not
>   guaranteed to be retrieved in the order in which they were inserted.

Answer (score 2):

It is the **[high water mark (HWM)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/glossary.htm#GUID-F3F5ACB2-94C8-483F-B427-1981836D0609)** concept.

> high water mark (HWM)
>
> The boundary between used and unused space in a segment.

Very well explained in detail by Thomas Kyte [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3A%3A%3A%3Ap11_question_id:492636200346818072).

Standard Oracle table is a **heap-organized** table. It is a table with rows stored in **no particular order**.

If you want to claim the free space, then you need to **reorganize** the table.